# Monte Carlo solver in parallel with QuTiP

Tags: parallel-processing, montecarlo, qutip

I'm trying to run some code in QuTiP, but when I run a function in parallel with `parfor` I am getting an error.

```
results= parfor(func2, range(len(delta)))
```

Error:

```
AssertionError
     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-206-6c2ffcb32b4f> in <module>()
----> 1 results= parfor(func2, range(len(delta)))

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qutip/parallel.pyc in parfor(func, *args, **kwargs)
    119     try:
    120         map_args = ((func, v, os.getpid()) for v in var)
--> 121         par_return = list(pool.map(task_func, map_args))
    122 
    123         pool.terminate()

/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    249         '''
    250         assert self._state == RUN
--> 251         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
    252 
    253     def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):

/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    556             return self._value
    557         else:
--> 558             raise self._value
    559 
    560     def _set(self, i, obj):

AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
```

Here is my code:

```
def func2(x):
    def H1_coeff(t,args):
       return exp(-((t-4)/2.0) ** 2)
    H0 = np.pi*w * a.dag() *a
    Hi= delta[x]*(a.dag())

    H = [H0, [Hi,H1_coeff]]
    result = mesolve(H, psi0, tlist, c_ops, [])
    numer=expect(n,result.states)

    print delta[x], "done"
    return numer
```

Does anybody know what's wrong here?

Comment: It's best to have your problem as close to the top of your question as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the definition of H1_coeff outside of func2.